# Groovy Spock test log HTTP requests to stdout

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

I was used to seeing all HTTP requests in the stdout tab of JUnit when running our Groovy Spock tests from Gradle. After a large upgrade (see [this large commit](https://github.com/yonadev/yona-server/commit/98cf88575a43f81a4127b621cd1f68280130b144)), this does not work anymore.

As this was very helpful when debugging a test failure, I'd love to get it back. None of the upgraded dependencies seems to be used in the Groovy Spock tests, so there is no obvious candidate. Next, I searched quite a bit for a property that would log the HTTP requests to stdout again, but I couldn't find it.

Anybody an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Bert

Answer (score 0):

Digging in further, it became clear that the change is caused by the upgrade of `org.springframework.boot` from `1.5.7.RELEASE` to `2.0.4.RELEASE`. With Spring Boot 1.5, LogBack was used and now JUL.

To get logging switched on again, I set a Java system property in `build.gradle`:

```
systemProperties = [
    "java.util.logging.config.file": "<some path>/logging.properties"
]
```

To get the logging I like, I put the following inside `logging.properties`:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS.%1$tL %4$-6s %2$s - %5$s%n

.level=FINEST
```

This way, Apache client again logs the HTTP requests:

```
20:16:32.050 FINE   groovyx.net.http.RESTClient doRequest - POST http://localhost:8082/users/?
20:16:32.611 FINE   org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager getConnection - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:8082
20:16:32.631 FINE   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator openConnection - Connecting to localhost:8082
20:16:32.660 FINE   org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies process - CookieSpec selected: default
```

This provides a great help when analyzing a test failure.